# How to handle img onChange event inside a React.js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have next and previous buttons and I want to traverse some images. When the user chooses next or previous I want the parent component to know about it.
My problem is that I can't seem to catch the `onChange` event from the child component `img` element. The image changes by updating the `img` `src` attribute.

It might be worth noting that if I do `<img onchange=alert('heelo') />` the `alert` fires correctly.

I have the following 2 components:

Child component:

```
var ImageViewer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            pages: [],
            currentPage: 0,
            imagePath: ""            
        };
    },
    handleImageLoad: function (event) {
        console.log("Image load event fired -->", event.target.tagName);        
        //this.setState({                
        //    currentPage: this.props.document.currentPage
        //}, function () {
        //    console.log("Current Page state is set");
        //    console.log(this.state.currentPage);                    
        //});

    },   
    errorLoadingImage: function (event) {
        console.log("Image load error event -->", event.target.tagName);
        console.log("pathname : " + window.location.pathname);
        var loginPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');        
        if (loginPath.length > 1) {
            //   window.location.replace("/" + loginPath[1]);
            window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
        } else {
            console.log("Error: Can not redirect user to login path");
            console.log("window.location : " + window.location);
            console.log("window.location.pathname : " + window.location.pathname);
        }
    },
    getImageSrc: function () {
        var imagePath = this.props.document.ImageRoute,
            imageDirectory = imagePath.substring(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        console.log("Image source from page : " +this.state.currentPage);
        //current page state gets update in prev and next events.
        var fileName = this.props.document.Pages[this.state.currentPage].FileName;
        console.log(fileName);
        console.log("loading file : " + imageDirectory + fileName);
        return (imageDirectory + fileName);
    },
    handleChange: function (event) {
        this.props.callback(event.target.value);
    },
    renderImage: function () {  
        if (this.props.document == null) {
            return <img src='' />;
        } else {            
            return <img className="imageDisplay" src={this.getImageSrc()} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} onLoad={this.handleImageLoad} onError={this.errorLoadingImage}/>;
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log("rendering image viewer")
        console.log("document is " + this.props.document)
        return (
            <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>              
                {this.renderPager()}     
                {this.renderImage()}                                                     
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Parent component:

```
var Workstation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            documentsInQueue: this.props.documentList,
            ImageSrc: this.props.imgSrc,
            currentDocument: null,
            currentPage : 0
        };
    },
    selectedDocument: function (document, clickedDocumentIndex) {
        console.log("selected document is :");
        console.log(document);
        console.log("clicked document index is :");
        console.log(clickedDocumentIndex);
        this.setState({ currentDocument: document }, function () {
            console.log("Image Route state is set")
            console.log(this.state.currentDocument.ImageRoute)
        });
    },
    onImageViewerPageChange: function (event) {
        console.log("current page from event : " + currentPage);
        this.setState({ currentPage: currentPage }, function () {
            console.log("Workstation: Current Page state is set")
            console.log(this.state.currentPage)
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="document col-md-2 border-outline">
                        <DocumentQueue initialData={this.state.documentsInQueue} imgSrc={this.state.ImageSrc} selectedDocument={this.selectedDocument} currentPage={this.state.currentPage}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-2 border-outline">                        
                        <Indexing document={this.state.currentDocument} />                                                          
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8 border-outline imageViewer">
                        <ImageViewer document={this.state.currentDocument} callback={this.onImageViewerPageChange}/>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: how does an img change?

Comment: I update the img src.

Comment: that should fire onload, but i've never heard of onchange firing from an img before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretical answer:

```
this.imageUrl = this.getImageSrc();
if this.previousUrl != this.imageUrl {
    this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
this.previousUrl = this.imageUrl;
return <img className="imageDisplay" src={this.imageUrl} onLoad={this.handleImageLoad} onError={this.errorLoadingImage}/>;
```

You may want to set state as a result of getImageSrc function and use that state in the view, and also move change checking logic into getImageSrc. So it re-renders the view properly

Comment: thats a great idea. This is along the lines of the reactjs guidelines for boolean shouldComponentUpdate(
  object nextProps, object nextState
)                                                                                                                                                                              However, i feel i was being verbose and i should be able to make onload work.

Comment: Well, if you execute that getImageSrc only if relevant prop changed should increase performance in case you have other props that may change. And if you re-save state, it will trigger the view rerender.